# Does Geocoder's `distance_to` calculation differ from `distance_between`?

Tags: ruby, geocoding

I'm using the Ruby [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) (1.1.6) and see behavior I don't understand. The following test failure demonstrates it.

```
it "calculates distance consistently" do
  one = FactoryGirl.create(:point, latitude: 1.0, longitude: 1.0)
  two = FactoryGirl.create(:point, latitude: 2.0, longitude: 2.0)

  expect(
    one.distance_to(two)
  ).to eq(
    Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(
      [one.latitude, one.longitude], [two.latitude, two.longitude]
    )
  )
end
```

This results in:

```
 Failure/Error: expect(
   expected: 97.69535411821234
        got: 157.22543203807288
   (compared using ==)
```

I see that `object.distance_to(other)` is supposed to be a "location-aware query", but in my test logs, I see only SQL inserts for the creates, no `SELECT` to get the distance. (I'm using PostgreSQL.)

Is my expectation here somehow incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

## Must specify units

A little code spelunking clarified this. I needed to add `{units: :km}` when calling `Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between`, because that's what the model is using.

I figured this out by:

- Calling `point.method(:distance_to).source_location`
- Seeing that pointed [here](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/blob/1.1.6/lib/geocoder/stores/base.rb#L28)
- Noticing that it calls the same method but adds the `units` option

Comment: Excellent, you where able to find the answer yourself. But reading the question and the answer I do not understand Geocoders fallbacks or defaults. When you do not provide a unit, why uses Geocoders *miles* as `unit` in `distance_to`, but *kilometers* in `distance_between`. That seems weird. Has is to do with some configuration in your code? Perhaps you like to explain that in your answer, that might be helpful for later visitors of this page.

Comment: @spickermann As I said, "I needed to add {unit: :km}... because that's what the model is using." The model was configured to use km, so `distance_to` used km.